# calling java method from unity c#

Tags: c#, java, android, plugins, unity-game-engine

Hello everyone,
              Can anyone tell me how to call java methods from unity c#.
I tried the following but its not working for me.

**In Unity :**

```
void OnGUI () {
    string somestring;
    AndroidJavaClass jc= new    AndroidJavaClass("com.example.pluginsample.MainActivity");
    AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
    somestring = jo.Call<string>("Foo");
    GUI.Label (new Rect (20, 20, 100, 20), somestring);
}
```

**In Java Class:**

```
public String Foo()
{
    return "Hello";        
}
```

Please help.I am stuck.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what "isn't working"? Is there an exception?

Check your java class has an instance() method that returns the java object:

```
public String Foo()
{
    return "Hello";        
}

public static MainActivity instance() {
    return new MainActivity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to be checked:

1. Have you declared your plugin activity to AndroidManifest.xml?
2. Is there any `instance` class property (static variable) in you plugin activity?
3. If two points above doesnt help, can you make the `Foo` method to be static?

Let me know if this solution still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The similar question I saw on unity forum. Do have a look at the question and [solution](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/330809/integration-of-jar-file-using-jni.html) for that. Its working.

Answer (score 0):

Make the function “Foo” public static as below

```
public static String Foo()
{
    return "Hello";        
}
```